# C++で書かれたプログラムのコンパイルエラー

Tags: c++, compiler

[参考サイト](https://gist.github.com/nadavrot/5b35d44e8ba3dd718e595e40184d03f0)に掲載されていたC++のプログラムをコンパイルしようとしています。
行列計算のプログラムで、実行形式ファイルとアセンブリコードの両方で、同じ６つのエラーが表示されました。
どのように修正すればコンパイルできるようになるでしょうか。

実行コマンド

```
$ g++ -o sample sample.cpp
```

```
$ g++ -S sample.cpp
```

エラー

```
sample.cpp:7:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'float8'; did you mean
      'float'?
  float8 csum[regsA][regsB] = {{0.0}};
  ^~~~~~
  float
sample.cpp:12:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'float8'; did you mean
      'float'?
      float8 bb = LoadFloat8(&B(p, bi * 8));
      ^~~~~~
      float
sample.cpp:12:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'B'
      float8 bb = LoadFloat8(&B(p, bi * 8));
                              ^
sample.cpp:14:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'float8'; did you mean
      'float'?
        float8 aa = BroadcastFloat8(A(ai, p));
        ^~~~~~
        float
sample.cpp:14:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'A'
        float8 aa = BroadcastFloat8(A(ai, p));
                                    ^
sample.cpp:23:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'C'
      AdduFloat8(&C(ai, bi * 8), csum[ai][bi]);
                  ^
6 errors generated.
```

float8とfloatに関してエラーが出ていたので、修正したところ以下のようになりました。

```
sample.cpp:12:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'B'
      float bb = LoadFloat8(&B(p, bi * 8));
                             ^
sample.cpp:14:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'A'
        float aa = BroadcastFloat8(A(ai, p));
                                   ^
sample.cpp:23:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'C'
      AdduFloat8(&C(ai, bi * 8), csum[ai][bi]);
                  ^
3 errors generated.
```

実行プログラム

```cpp
template <unsigned regsA, unsigned regsB>
void matmul_dot_inner(int k, const float *a, int lda, const float *b, int ldb,
                      float *c, int ldc) {
  float csum[regsA][regsB] = {{0.0}};
  for (int p = 0; p < k; p++) {

    // Perform the DOT product.
    for (int bi = 0; bi < regsB; bi++) {
      float bb = LoadFloat8(&B(p, bi * 8));
      for (int ai = 0; ai < regsA; ai++) {
        float aa = BroadcastFloat8(A(ai, p));
        csum[ai][bi] += aa * bb;
      }
    }
  }

  // Accumulate the results into C.
  for (int ai = 0; ai < regsA; ai++) {
    for (int bi = 0; bi < regsB; bi++) {
      AdduFloat8(&C(ai, bi * 8), csum[ai][bi]);
    }
  }
}
```

できていること
C++のHello world.は実行確認できています。

```
$ g++ -o hello hello.cpp
$ ./hello 
Hello world.
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "Hello world." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに含まれる`did you mean 'float'?`と言うのは「`float`のつもりだった(のに`float8`と打ち間違えた)のか?」と聞いているだけなので、そう書き換えれば動くようになると言うものではありません。参考サイトでは`float8`型(32-bit float x 8 のSIMDベクトル型)を意図的に使用していますので、それを単なる`float`型に書き換えてしまっては、たとえコンパイルを通すことはできても意味のある動作はさせられません。なお、metropolisさんが見つけられたリンク先を見る限りgccのSIMD拡張を使用しているようですが、MIPSならSIMDレジスタは128bitなので、`float8`は使えない、と言うことになります。(大文字の)`A`, `B`, `C`などの定義は記事中にも、上記のリンク先にも見当たらないので、そこらへんは自分でわかる人用の記事になっている、と言えるでしょう。前質問のコメントにも書きましたが、参考記事はあくまで概念を説明しただけのものと捉えて、同じ動作をご自身のターゲットに応じた書き方に書き換える必要があるでしょう。どちらにしろ、目先を変えただけの質問を再投稿するのではなく、元質問のコメント等に答えながらそちらに集中した方が解決策を得るには早道だと思います。

Comment: @OOPer コメントいただきましてありがとうございます。stackoverflowの信頼度の都合で２度目のコメントができないようで、質問させていただきました。

Comment: @OOPer 「参考記事はあくまで概念を説明しただけのもの」ということですが、C++では行優先・列優先の実装が可能で、Cでは行優先・列優先の実装ができないという理解で合ってますでしょうか。そのため、C++での質問をさせていただきました。

Comment: 私のコメントのどこにも、そして参考記事中のどこにも行優先・列優先なんて話は出てきていないのに、なぜそんな理解になるのかが理解できないのですが、合っていません。

Comment: @OOPer 「前質問のコメントにも書きましたが、参考記事はあくまで概念を説明しただけのものと捉えて、同じ動作をご自身のターゲットに応じた書き方に書き換える必要があるでしょう。」とありましたので、前質問の「行優先・列優先でデータを格納し、高性能な行列乗算のプログラム」についても含めてのご回答と理解しました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確かに質問者さんが前提と思っていらっしゃる事柄を、自分が全く理解できないからと言って無視しておいて、「自分はそんなことを一言も言っていない」と言う言い方は乱暴すぎたようです。失礼いたしました。また別コメントで「gccのSIMD拡張」と書いてしまいましたが、実際には参考記事にはClangと明記してありますね。この点についてもお詫びいたします。さて、繰り返しになりますが、参考記事は行優先の行列を少しでも高速に解くためのもので、列優先という言葉で通常表されるような要素はありません。従って、あなたが「行優先・列優先」とおっしゃる意味が全く理解できません。いったいどのような意味で「行優先・列優先」とおっしゃっているのかご説明いただければ、何らかのお手伝いができるのではないかと考えている読者の方がいらっしゃるかと思います。ぜひご説明をお願いします。

Comment: @OOPer ご丁寧にありがとうございます。
データ保持形式における列優先，行優先を指しております（参考：https://qiita.com/suzuryo3893/items/9e543cdf8bc64dc7002a）
正方行列 A * B （双方とも行列数は同じ場合）を行う時に、Aは行優先データ順、Bは列優先データ順にメモリへ格納して、行列A・Bともに行優先データ順もしくは行列A・Bともに列優先データ順の時よりも、効率よく計算時にアクセスできるプログラムを書くことを目的としています。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。ご指摘されたように、Aを行優先、Bを列優先とすると、行列積の計算が大変効率的に(メモリ参照の局所性を含めキャッシュやメモリバンド幅の有効利用の上でも)実行できるのはよく知られたところです。残念ながらあなたが参考サイトとして示された内容は、**AもBも行優先の状況で、いかにキャッシュやメモリバンド幅を有効に利用するか** と言う観点で解説されており、**Bは列優先データ順にメモリ格納** するのとは全く別のアプローチです。Aを行優先、Bを列優先とするアプローチを取りたいのであれば、参考サイトに上げられたのとは別サイトを探していただかないといけないでしょう。

Comment: ご説明いただきましてありがとうございました。大変助かりました。